# How to validate an HTML element within an 'if-else' statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, dom

I am trying to validate the text content of an element that can only be captured by targeting class and tag names. The text content I am looking for is available by querying 'document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent', but in cases where the element or any of its precursors are not on the page, this will throw an  error. Is there a better way to check that the text content exists within the conditional, without repeating the checks for each element along the way?

Here is the current implementation:

```
(function() {
    if (!!document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].children[1] && 
    !!document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0] && 
    !!document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent) {
        return document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent;
    } else {
        return 'Text not present.';
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.

Comment: The HTML is not available, but the basic premise is that all of the elements on every level are dynamic, and may or may not be present on the page.

Comment: It could certainly be improved by using `.querySelector()`, but without seeing the markup writing that will prove difficult.

Comment: What error is raised, exactly? And why do you have `if( !!document...`)?

Comment: you could try something along the lines of
`var x =document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
if(x.length >0)
 return document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent;
else
 return 'Text not present.';`

Comment: `!!` casts to Boolean. Ever heard of a `var`?

Comment: rather than complicating it in if statement. Try putting in variables and then used the variable with if.  example var x =  document.getElementById("myDIV");
x.getElementsByClassName("child")[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";

Comment: @Dai For example, if there are no elements with the class name 'sample' on the page, there will be an uncaught error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined'.

Comment: @HussainPatel That would still throw the error if the element is not on the page.

Comment: @kshishoo That would still throw the error if the element is not on the page when trying to set the variable 'x'.

Comment: agreed, as the html is not shared, I assume the element exist on the page and simplifying the if statement will help debug it..

Comment: Try using a variable so you don't have to repeat the long expression `document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0].children[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` exist.

```
(function() {
  var el = document.querySelector("sample > :nth-child(2) span")
  return el && el.textContent ? el.textContent : "Text not present.";
})();
```

The `:nth-child()` selector is 1-based, so that's why it uses `:nth-child(2)` where you used `.children[1]`.

---

Or at the very least, use variables.

```
(function() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0];
  el = el && el.children[1] && el.children[1].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
  return el && el.textContent ? el.textContent : "Text not present.";
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, put it in variable rather than complicating the if statement.

```
function myFunction() {
var x = !document.getElementsByClassName('sample')[0];
    if (!x.children[1] && !!x.children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0] && 
    !!x.children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent) 
    {
    return x.children[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent;
    } 
else {
    return 'Text not present.';
}
```